# SQL Server Update with left join and group by having

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I'm making an update to our database and would like to update rows that do not have existing items in another table.  I can join the tables together, but am  having trouble grouping the table to get a count of the number of rows

```
UPDATE dpt
SET dpt.active = 0 
FROM DEPARTMENT dpt
LEFT JOIN DOCUMENTS doc on dpt.ID = doc.DepartmentID
GROUP BY dpt.ID
HAVING COUNT(doc.ID) = 0
```

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
UPDATE DEPARTMENT
   SET active = 0 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                    FROM DOCUMENTS doc
                   WHERE doc.departmentid = id)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be Señor...unless you were trying to insinuate that OMG Ponies is old!  LOL

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE  department
SET     active = 0
WHERE   id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  departmentId
        FROM    doc
        )
```